# How to recreate a angular 6 reactive form control with using new field object and place it in existing position

Tags: angular

I am trying insert a new field and i don't know its the write word to use create a form control for new field and add in the existing form index, 
for example if i have 3 input fields rendered at initial response, if i click change button in side of a field it should change to radio button in the same index position of form.

here is the code i have tried, html

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let item of listData; let i = index">
<div class="inputFeild">
        <label>{{i +' '+ item.label}}</label>
    <input [type]="item.controlType" [formControlName]="item.name">

    </div>
    <div (click)="changeMe(item.name,i)">change me</div>
    <br />
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid">submit</button>

            </div>
</form>
```

and ts

```
  public registerForm: FormGroup;
  listData = [{
     label: "First Name",
     controlType: "text",
     name:"firstName"
    },
    {
      label: "Last Name",
      controlType: "text",
      name:"lastName"
     },
     {
      label: "School Name",
      controlType: "text",
      name:"schoolName"
     },
     {
      label: "College Name",
      controlType: "text",
      name:"collegeName"
     },
    ]


    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {


      this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
      this.listData.forEach(item => {
        // if (field.type === "button") return;
        const control = this.formBuilder.control(
          null,
          Validators.required);
        this.registerForm.addControl(item.name, control);
      });
  }

  changeMe(questionName, groupIndex){
    const changeData = {

      controlType: 'radio',
        name: 'country',
        label: 'Country',
        value: 'in',
        required: true,
        options: [
          { key: 'm', label: 'Male' },
          { key: 'f', label: 'Female' }
        ]

    }

    this.listData[groupIndex].label = "test change";

  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xarhi?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Where is your html for the radio buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SWITCH structural directive to choose between control types and when you change the data of the array, the view is going to change too.

So, it is not hard to build.

Good luck!

Comment: can you give an example